# What is the effect of changing the maximum value of iterations in k-means clustering?

Tags: matlab, k-means, surf, matlab-cvst

In Matlab, I'm creating a visual codebook using Bag of Features with the SURF features of 3913 images and k = 450. I train an SVM classifier with the visual codebook, and then use it to classify video frames to detect humans. The video I'm using is an aerial one. My maximum number of iterations is 100 by default, but when I ran the code, I get a warning from Matlab that says "Failed convergence at 100 iterations". What does this mean? Does it affect my clustering? I only have 2 classes: person and nonperson. Does it also mean that I have to increase my maximum iterations for better results or do I have to decrease it?

Comment: `100` is too low for iteration, it's default value is `1500`. The affection is that there won't be any classification if `SVM` doesn't converge.

Comment: Are you using your own implementation of bag of features, or are you using the built-in functions from the Computer Vision System Toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

When you say 100 iterations, are you talking about the clustering, i. e. building the "visual vocabulary"?  If so, then the message you are getting would indicate that the k-means clustering was not able to converge after 100 iterations. That means the centers of clusters are moving after each iteration by an amount greater than what is specified in the convergence criterion. The most reasonable thing to do would be to run k-means for more iterations.